# Spring boot application properties override

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have a problem with my application properties' file.

I have some property defined in application.properties
like below

```yaml
A:
 B:
  C:
   test: lala
```

I have some properties defined in application-local.properties

```yaml
A:
 processor: juju
```

Let's assume I run the application using the local profile.
The problem is that in my ConfigurationProperties, the property A.B.C.test is null

```java
@Data
@Validated
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "A.B.C.test")
```

Comment: If you have `@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "A.B.C.test")` , say we have a `private String name;`, you have to set props in .properties file like this `A.B.C.test.name=myName`, isn't it ?

Comment: if you are using a properties file use A.B.C.test = value or if you are using yml file then it should be 
spring:
   application:
      name: demoservice

Answer (score 0):

if you are using a properties file use

```
A.B.C.test = value
```

or if you are using yml file then it should be

```
A:
 B:
  C: 
   test: value
```